# How to make a dockable window in tcl/tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a way in tcl/Tk to make a window dockable, so that it could be on its own, or embedded as a widget in another window?

I'm using Tcl 8.4 and upgrading is not an option.

Comment: Is upgrading Windows XP not an option? You should really upgrade your software after it reached EOL.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, it's not my call.

Comment: Well, I just try to give some reasons why they should do it, so you can convince them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but only starting with Tk 8.5 which introduced the `wm manage` and `wm forget` subcommands to the `wm` command.

See [TIP #125](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/125.html) or a recent Tk manpage for the details.

Tcl 8.4 reached end-of-life after 11 years, the last release was 8.4.20, there will be no more updates to that line.

A simple example for `wm manage` and `wm forget`:

```
package require Tk 8.5

proc undock {b widget} {
    wm manage $widget
    $b configure -command [list dock $widget] -text "Dock"
}

proc dock {b widget} {
    wm forget $widget
    grid $widget -sticky news
    $b configure -command [list undock $widget] -text "Undock"    
}

frame .docked
button .docked.undock -command { undock .docked.undock .docked } -text "Undock"
grid .docked -sticky news
grid .docked.undock -sticky news
```

Comment: How would you implement this in Tk 8.5?

Comment: Well, technically you can even do dockable windows in 8.4, but only via cheating. You would have to completely recreate the window hierarchy inside a new toplevel, which is error prone, slow and totally not nice.

Comment: There's an example of an undockable toolbar in the Tk 8.5 widget demonstrator (which should be distributed with any Tk distribution, but I'm a bit hazy about if that's actually done on Linux; I know it's part of the official Tk source distribution and also ActiveTcl). I wrote that demo precisely to show that sort of thing off.